# got a .tar.bz2 file for gentoo installation. Expecting .iso file

Tags: system-installation, gentoo

I downloaded stage3 tarball for amd64 from gentoo download page. The file contains image of root file system.
I was expecting an iso file because the handbook doesn't talk about this file. It says I am supposed to burn .iso into a CD and boot into it. But the gentoo servers don't have any iso file in the directory mentioned by the manual page.

FAQ page doesn't have question regarding this either. any input from experienced user would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the documented instructions for installing Gentoo from the stage3 tarball:

[Installing a stage tarball](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Stage)

Comment: That page assumes you already have a working unix prompt infront of you whether it be from a live cd or another distro.  What I didn't realize was I could just as well use existing Arch linux install to stage partitions on which to install gentoo and chroot into it. I did just that and installed gentoo alongside Arch. thanks Tim.